# How to add "tag" to a python class instance for identification purpose?

Tags: python, class, object, uniqueidentifier, identification

I'm currently working with the API of a 3D software (blender 3d)
Where we can create a subclass called "VertexGroup" (which basically is used to store vertex weight information).

[image]
[image]

I'm adding up functionalities to these class instances in my python script, where the users could generate procedural vertex-groups via some math algorithm. the only problem is that **I cannot identify the instances correctly**. In the present situation my script is relying on a built-in "name" string attr accessible by the user. which means that if the user changes this attribute I lost track of the instance.

So my question is the following, **how can I identify an instance of this Class**? Is there some way I could "tag" the class to recognize it later?

Here are a Few Things I did try already without success:

- using another attr from this class, unfortunately, there's none I could use for identification purposes.
- Adding my own properties to this Class via the built-in properties management given in the API, unfortunately, custom properties are not supported for this specific case, so i need to find a more pythonic way.
- adding new attributes to the class, unfortunately the class don't have any `__dict__` method it only have `__doc__` `__module__` `__slots__`and are all read-only.
- using id() or hash() is what i need right? unfortunately, it won't work in this case because the software is dynamically re-allocating this object in memory, so these identifiers may change during the object lifetime.
- creating a subclass of VertexGroup, unfortunately, it's not supported by the software API.

Comment: The last few bullets of your "I tried this:" list didn't come out properly bulleted.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion on something that i might overlook?

Comment: If you can't add attributes, or attributes can be changed by the user, and id and memory location are volatile, I'd have run out of ideas too.

Comment: how about implementing in your class the [comparison](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons) method such as == and < > (if those make sense), those are `__eq__`, `__lt__` and `__gt__` respectively, with those your class will be comparable and sortable by whatever criteria you desire

Answer (score 0):

To get the class of an object `obj`:

```
type(obj)
```

To check whether an object `obj` is compatible with class `cls`:

```
isinstance(obj, cls)
```

Comment: That will help me identify if my object is an instance from my class, 
i don't need this, i need a way to identify an instance, save it a sort of identifier somewhere to recognize my instance later (id and hash won't work in this case)